# Different ORDER BY based on criteria matched?

Tags: sql, criteria, sql-order-by

Is it possible with SQL to order the returned rows differently based on what criteria was matched?

For example, my webpage allows inputting a name or zip code. The query currently orders by last name, first name. That's great, unless they input a zip code I'd then want to order the results by zip code instead of name. Is that possible? I'd like this to occur in the same query rather than two. A potential problem: What if the inputted value matches both the name and zip?

Thanks!

Pseudo query:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, zip
From Users
WHERE (FirstName LIKE 'search' OR LastName LIKE 'search' OR Zip LIKE 'search')
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: You'll need to know whether the search entry is a name or a zip code - then you could "ORDER BY CASE @mode WHEN 'Name' THEN LastName ELSE Zip END"

Comment: @JohnBingham I don't think his query knows or wants to know about the mode: whatever matches the criteria, "makes the cut", no matter on what field it is. For example, if there's a `'Mr. Smith91228'` in the database, he'll be chosen along with the residents of the `91228` ZIP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the query is formulated in a way to guess which field matches the search condition, you may want to try guessing which one has matched in the `ORDER BY` as well:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, zip
From Users
WHERE (FirstName LIKE 'search' OR LastName LIKE 'search' OR Zip LIKE 'search')
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN FirstName LIKE 'search' THEN FirstName ELSE NULL END
,   CASE WHEN LastName LIKE 'search' THEN LastName ELSE NULL END
,   CASE WHEN Zip LIKE 'search' THEN Zip ELSE NULL END
```

This assumes, of course, that `'search'` stands for something that you pass to your query that is a meaningful parameter of the `LIKE` operator, i.e. has metacharacters, has been properly formatted, and so on.

Comment: This should work great! Thanks! Now I would like to order by last name then first name, but putting a comma in breaks it. Can you tell me how to get both in there? CASE WHEN zip LIKE 'search' THEN zip END,
    CASE WHEN LastName LIKE 'search' THEN LastName ELSE LastName END

Comment: @Jordan You can use concatenation to concatenate strings, like this: `LastName || ',' || FirstName`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, zip From Users
WHERE (FirstName LIKE '%search%' OR LastName LIKE '%search%' OR Zip LIKE '%search%')
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

If possible, try to replace LIKE with = . It improves the speed of the query. 
Anyways, why don´t you do an if-else block ?

Pseudocode:

```
if (input = name){
    SELECT firstName, lastName, zip From Users
    WHERE (FirstName LIKE '%search%' OR LastName LIKE '%search%')
    ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
}
else if (input = zipcode) {
    SELECT firstName, lastName, zip From Users
    WHERE Zip LIKE '%search%'
    ORDER BY zip
}
```